# Xcode 4.1 installation not customizable? Missing Installation Type Step?

Tags: ios-appstore, xcode, ios

Any ideas on how to get around installing that huge iOS SDK in Xcode 4.1?

[This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15231/minimal-xcode-installation-without-ios-sdk) Q&A suggests to deselect iOS SDK during installation, but the Xcode 4.1 (App Store-Version) Installer seems to have no "Installation Type" Step anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turms out Apple released a commandline tools package recently, which seems to be exactly what I need: [Apple Developer Downloads](http://developer.apple.com/downloads)

Answer (score 1):

You can control or right click to show package contents and run only select portions of Xcode 4.1.

The program [Pacifist](http://www.charlessoft.com/) will let you look into the packages to see what each contains.

The installer has changed to remove the options - it's all or nothing. If space is tight on your boot drive, you will have to either install to another volume and move parts back or temporarily free up enough space to install and clean out what you don't want to keep.

Comment: Thx. There are 58 packages there. Quiet daunting task to decide which ones are required for building homebrew software for me. Are there any guidelines? Does the order matter?

Comment: Yes - It gets very slow and makes me just install Xcode to an external drive or free up space temporarily, and delete the Platform / SDK folders I don't need on any given mac.

Comment: I guess, when i do a selective install like you suggest appstore updates will no longer work?

Comment: Yes - if you don't get the overall Xcode package receipt - the software update process might not show you updates. I haven't picked apart this version to know what it looks for - I just do the whole deal and delete things I don't want at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

- Right-click on `Install XCode.app` and choose "Show Package Contents"
- Browse to Contents->Resources and run `Xcode.mpkg`
- Customize your install, leave out the iOS SDK, save 5 GB of disk space
- Profit?